# Get All links of website Facebook Share Count using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am using this script to get Facebook share

```
<h2>
    Facebook Share of Bing 
</h2>

<span class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>


<script>
    getfbcount(url);

    //Facebook
    function getfbcount(url){
        var url = 'http://www.bing.com';
        $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
            $(".mod-share-nota-count.likes").text(data[url].shares);
        });
    }    
</script>
```

and get the actual share of bing but when I add more like this script to my website like this it would not work perfectly

Here is the demo- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk67pe5r/1/)

```
<!-- Twitter Share -->

<h2>
    Facebook Share of Twitter 
</h2>

<span class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>


<script>
    getfbcount(url);

    //Facebook
    function getfbcount(url){
        var url = 'http://www.twitter.com';
        $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
            $(".mod-share-nota-count.likes").text(data[url].shares);
        });
    }    
</script>


<!-- Facebook Share -->

<h2>
    Facebook Share of Facebook
</h2>

<span class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>


<script>
    getfbcount(url);

    //Facebook
    function getfbcount(url){
        var url = 'http://www.facebook.com';
        $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
            $(".mod-share-nota-count.likes").text(data[url].shares);
        });
    }    
</script>


<!-- Google Share Share -->

<h2>
    Facebook Share of Google
</h2>

<span class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>


<script>
    getfbcount(url);

    //Facebook
    function getfbcount(url){
        var url = 'http://www.goolge.com';
        $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
            $(".mod-share-nota-count.likes").text(data[url].shares);
        });
    }    
</script>


<!-- Bing Share Share -->

<h2>
    Facebook Share of Bing 
</h2>

<span class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>


<script>
    getfbcount(url);

    //Facebook
    function getfbcount(url){
        var url = 'http://www.bing.com';
        $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
            $(".mod-share-nota-count.likes").text(data[url].shares);
        });
    }    
</script>
```

Some can give me the solution or what I am  missing in this script

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) define multiple methods with the same name. You already have the method set up to take a URL as a parameter, so you can start using that to your advantage to make a single re-usable method (which is the whole point of them anyway). Let's change it a bit to contain only what it says it's going to to: "Get FB Count":

```
function getfbcount(url, callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, callback);
}
```

Now we have a simple method that takes a URL, but with a callback, since `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and we don't know when it will return. We use that to pass along what needs to happen once the request completes.

You can also simplify your markup. First, I would change your markup to something like this. This keeps the data you need right there where its result is going to show up, and makes adding additional sites very easy.

```
<span data-url="http://www.facebook.com" class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>
<span data-url="http://www.twitter.com" class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>
<span data-url="http://www.google.com" class="mod-share-nota-count likes">0</span>
```

And now you can run a single little script when the DOM is ready that loops through all the spans it finds, pulls the URL from the custom `data-url` attribute, executes the `getfbcount` method, and updates the span with the result.

```
function getfbcount(url, callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, callback);
}

$(function() {
    $('.mod-share-nota-count.likes').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        getfbcount(url, function(result) {
            $(this).text(result[url].shares);
        };
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwpqy3x5/1/)**

Now all you need to change to add additional like counts is more HTML markup. Now, let me finally add that I've never used the FB graph system -- maybe there's a better way where you can send multiple URLs at a time to it. That would be ideal to reduce the number of requests your page is making.

Comment: _“maybe there's a better way where you can send multiple URLs at a time to it”_ – there is: Values for multiple URLs can be queried by comma-separating them, like this: `?ids=url1,url2,url3` The limit for the number of values in the `ids` parameter is 50; although with URLs as “ids” it might be advisable to use less, before the whole API request URL gets to long. And if the URLs used are not always this “basic”, but might contain special characters/query strings themselves, using `encodeURIComponent` on them before putting them into the parameter value is also recommendable.

Comment: @SudhansuNayak: You can remove the outer document ready code; change the fiddle setting from onLoad to No wrap - body. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/wwpqy3x5/1/

Comment: @cory But why result shows  000 in share of the url

Comment: @SudhansuNayak: Unfortunately I'm at work and Facebook is blocked -- I can't test exactly what `result` is when it comes back. I suspect that `result` in the `$get.JSON` callback doesn't jive with the code `result[url].shares`.